# How to save the best estimator of a RandomizedSearchCV object using Tensorflow SavedModel?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, scikit-learn, python-3.7

I am trying to save the best estimator from RandomizedSearchCV object using SavedModel format. I know that we can also save it using `joblib.dump` but I need it to be in the SavedModel format.

Commonly, I always use:

```
...
..
.
model.fit(X,y,epochs=1000)
model.save_model("MyModel")
```

to save my trained-model (with no hyper parameter optimisation)

However, this time it did not work when I tried:

```
.....
...
..
result = RandomizedSearchCV(*args)
result.best_estimator_.save_model("MyModel")
```

where the error says that:

```
RandomizedSearchCV object does not have attribute saved_model
```

Any help will be very appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure your model is fitted?

Comment: hi david. yes I did.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, you called `best_estimator_.saved_model("MyModel")` instead of `best_estimator_.save_model("MyModel")`. So that typo was probably your mistake.

This worked for me:

```
model_search = RandomizedSearchCV()
best_model = model_search.best_estimator_
best_model.save_model("model.json")
```